# Ribbon in WinForms C# .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ribbon, ribbon-control

Does Microsoft have ribbon control for non-Office applications? If not is there any that are available for free?

I like that component and would like to use it my WinForm 4.0 application.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Microsoft makes one for WPF that you can download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11877).

There is an [open source ribbon](https://github.com/RibbonWinForms/RibbonWinForms) that should work for traditional WinForms.

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft have made a bit of a mess of providing a Ribbon control.  Initially it had some very [complex licence conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/aa973809.aspx), these may be relaxed now but the control is not as easily available as some of their recent [NuGet](http://nuget.org/) deployed goodies.

There seem to be more options in the WPF area if that helps:

1. WPF - [Microsoft Ribbon for WPF October 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877), this replaces[WPF Ribbon Preview](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Ribbon%20Preview&ProjectName=wpf)
2. [New .NET 4.5 WPF Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ribbon_control) - RC but at least it is in the framework
3. [Fluent Ribbon Control Suite](http://fluent.codeplex.com/)

In general, WinForms seems to be a dead-end and I wouldn't expect to see Microsoft invest too much in it but libraries/examples do exist:

1. Commercial library: [ComponentOne Ribbon](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/RibbonWinForms/)
2. Commercial library: [Infragistics WinToolbars](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/wintoolbars.aspx#Overview)
3. Blog about using the [Microsoft Windows 7 SDK](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/windows-7-ribbon-for-winforms-yes-you.html) ribbon
4. [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25907/A-Professional-Ribbon-You-Will-Use-Now-with-orb)
5. [CodeProject post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25907/A-Professional-Ribbon-You-Will-Use-Now-with-orb) using the Windows 7 SDK

Answer (score 1):

The one mentioned on CodePlex was a good first effort but there's been no release since 2009 and it doesn't offer much functionality.

There's a complete package available on CodePlex that's active and full featured. You can get it [here](http://windowsribbon.codeplex.com/).

This is a .NET wrapper around the Windows 7 Ribbon Control and while it does require the Windows SDK to compile, it works great for WinForms apps that want to incorporate a ribbon without incurring the overhead cost of a commercial product.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest commercial UI libraries by DevExpress:

- [WinForms Ribbon](https://www.devexpress.com/winforms/ribbon/)
- [WPF Ribbon](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/wpf/bars/)
- [WinUI Ribbon Toolbar](https://www.devexpress.com/winui/)

You can download their free 30-day trial at https://www.devexpress.com/try